# Unable to draw Route between two location in Android

Tags: google-maps

I am working with google map for some days. I have developed a small project through which i can track my location and five nearest ATM booths in a list. When i click on a booth then it shows two markers in google map: one is my location and the other is a ATM booth. Now i want to draw the route between my location and the booth. How can i do this? Please anyone help me.

Best wishes
Md. Fazla Rabbi

Answer (score 0):

[heres an tutorial which i found usefull regarding your query](http://capycoding.blogspot.in/2012/10/draw-route-between-two-point-on-google.html)

Hope it helps

Thanks